# Why no FirebaseDatabase Query Method to Get Value that Returns Task?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using [FirebaseDatabase](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/database/package-summary) to perform background syncing of app data.  The processing runs on a worker thread in an `IntentService`.  Because the syncing involves many sequential steps to read and write values to the database, I found it simpler to block and wait for each step to complete (or time out) instead of completion listeners.

For write operations, this is straightforward, using the form of [DatabaseReference.setValue()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference) that returns a [Task](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task) and the [Tasks.await()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Tasks) methods.

For read operations, I had to write my own class using [Query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/database/Query) and a [Semaphore](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) that is released when the listener fires.

Why is there no `Query` method to get a value that returns a `Task` with a result type that contains the `DataSnaphot` and `DatabaseError` objects?